# Returning the value in a promise.then

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have read some topics related to this but did not help, or I could not make them work. I have:

```
exports.findBookRating = (book) => {
var average;
Review.findAll({
    where: {
        bookId: book.id
    },
    attributes: [[sequelize.fn('avg', sequelize.col('rating')), 'avg_rated']],
    raw: true
})
.then(number => {
    average = number[0].avg_rated;

    console.log(average); //this works
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

console.log(average) // this does not work
}
```

I wanted to return *number[0].avg_rated*, and that is why I created that *average* variable but it did not work, can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Promise.findA" is async, while the rest is sync. Your last line will execute before your Promise resolved and thus returning "undefined".

Comment: As in the dupe, hence this should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

your `Review.findAll` is asynchronous which means right after it's called, it'll proceed to your `console.log(average) // this does not work`

And since it is asynchronous, by the time the `console.log(average) // this does not work` is called, `average` might not have yet been set.

Continue your code inside the `.then` part or use `await` if you need the value from an async call.

Example of using `await`:

```
const number = await Review.findAll()
const average = number[0].avg_rated
```

Comment: As in the dupe, hence this should be closed.

Comment: I cannot comment because I need more rep so I just posted an answer instead.

Comment: But it's a dupe, so neither are necessary.